# How do I create a crud for my entity called "rijles" , I have made this function so far, what are my next steps?

Tags: symfony5.4

> How do I create a crud for my entity called "rijles" ,  I have made this function so far, what are my next steps?
> There are lot of code off the formtype, as you can see in the code I made a code of RijlesType Form, also code for comments in user form.
> Let me know what I am doing wrong? I want to make sure that I understand.

```
#[Route('/klant/rijles', name: 'app_klant_rijles')]
    public function rijles(): Response
    {
        $rijlessen = $this->getUser()->getRijles2();
        return $this->render('klant/rijles.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'KlantController',
            'rijlessen' => $rijlessen
        ]);
    }

> Repository voor User

    /**
     * @return User[] Returns an array of User objects
     */
    public function findUser(): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.roles like :role')
            ->setParameter('role', '%KLANT%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }

> /** Voor Flash

* {# read and display all flash messages #}
*    {% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
*        {% for message in messages %}
*            <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
*                {{ message }}
*                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
*           </div>
*        {% endfor %}
*   {% endfor %}
*/


> RijlesType

->add('klant', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'choice_label' => 'email',
                'choices' => $this->userRepository->findUser()
            ])
            ->add('opslaan', SubmitType::class)
```